# VirtualBox error with Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to work on a coding project and cannot open my Ubuntu virtual machine with Oracle VM VirtualBox. I took a snapshot yesterday at about 11, and it was working fine. Several times I closed and reopened it. Today when I tried to open it, I kept getting the error below.

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.
>
> VM cannot start because the saved state file **'C:\Users\Tyler\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit\Snapshots\2014-01-30T19-59-05-976647800Z.sav'** is invalid (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). Deleted the saved state prior to starting the VM.

I tried deleting the file as it said, but none of the snapshots would open still. The file is still in my recycling bin. What can I do? Also, I took the 1/31 snapshot today before I deleted the previous one.

[image: VirtualBox - Error]

Comment: The file is corrupt.  There isn't a great deal you can do.  Why are you removing old working snapshots?

Comment: It told me to. None of them worked anyways.